# Elegant way to initialize array of structs in C++98

Tags: c++, initialization, c++98

I am using gcc version 4.9.2
If I compile using the compiler flag -std=c++0x the following code compiles OK.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
typedef struct
{
    vector<int> a;
    int b;
} MYTYPE;

int main(void)
{
    MYTYPE test[]=
    {
        { {1,2,3},4},
        { {5,6},7},
        { {},8}
    };
}
```

If I remove the -std=c++0x flag then the compiler reports:

> error: could not convert ‘{1, 2, 3}’ from ‘’ to ‘std::vector’

What is an elegant way to initialize test[] ?

Comment: unrelated: `typedef struct { ... } name;` is unecessary in C++ since `struct name { ... };` is enough to use `name` as a type (no `struct` needed like in C)

Comment: Not a good duplicate. The complexity here is that the vector element is a user defined type.

Comment: @Holt: Feel free to submit an answer based on that "copy paste", and see how it performs in the voting.

Comment: @Holt: No I wouldn't downvote on that basis. I would downvote if the answer wasn't useful in my opinion, and upvote if the converse were true, which it might be. My mind is open on that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With C++98, the best one can achive is probably the definition and use of an helper function:

```
struct Data
{
    std::vector<int> vector;
    int scalar;
};

template<std::size_t N>
Data make_data(const int (&vector)[N], int scalar)
{
    Data result;
    result.vector.assign(vector, vector+N);
    result.scalar = scalar;
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    const int vector[] = {1,2,3}; // just to annoy people using namespace std :)
    Data d = make_data(vector, 4);
    std::cout << d.vector[2] << "\n" << d.scalar << "\n";
}
```

[live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5854e20231fad1ce)

Comment: But you cannot do like that in pre-c++11 `Data dd[] = {  make_data({3, 2, 4}, 1) };`  - I mean necessity to define extra arrays - it is something not really "elegant"?.

Answer (score 4):

Other than achieving some semblance of elegance at the calling site by writing a set of hideous constructors in your `struct`, there is no particularly elegant way of initialising an array of these `struct`s pre-C++11.

It was for precisely these constructs that the C++11 syntax was developed.